# win32/gdi drawing lines or make a pixel move

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, c++17, gdi+, gdi

this is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { 

    
    HDC device_context = GetDC(hWnd);
    static int dotx = 50;
    static int doty = 50;
    static COLORREF color = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    bool w = false, a = false, s = false, d = false;
    bool lbutton = false;
    unsigned short prevx = 0;
    unsigned short prevy = 0;

    switch (msg) {  
    case WM_PAINT:
    {

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        int size = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                SetPixel(hdc, dotx + i, doty + j, color);
            }
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    }

    case WM_KEYDOWN:    
    {

        switch (wParam)
        {
        case 'W':
            w = true;
            break;
        case 'A':
            a = true;
            break;
        case 'S':
            s = true;
            break;
        case 'D':

            d = true;
        }

        // w

        if (w == true) {

            doty--;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (w == true && a == true) {

            dotx--;
            doty--;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (w == true && d == true) {

            dotx++;
            doty--;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        // a

        if (a == true) {

            dotx--;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (a == true && w == true) {

            doty--;
            dotx--;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (a == true && s == true) {

            doty++;
            dotx--;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }
        
        // s

        if (s == true) {

            doty++;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (s == true && a == true) {

            dotx--;
            doty++;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (s == true && d == true) {

            dotx++;
            doty++;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        // d

        if (d == true) {

            dotx++;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (d == true && s == true) {

            dotx++;
            doty++;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        if (d == true && w == true) {

            dotx++;
            doty--;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        }

        // end

        if (wParam == 'F') {

            HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(0, 150, 0));

            SelectObject(device_context, pen);

            MoveToEx(device_context, 100, 100, nullptr);
            LineTo(device_context, 300, 300);

            SetWindowText(hWnd, L"second title");

        }

        ReleaseDC(hWnd, device_context);

    }

    break;

    case WM_KEYUP:
    {

        switch (wParam) {

        case 'W': {

            w = false;

        }

        break;

        case 'A': {

            a = false;

        }
        
        break;

        case 'S': {

            s = false;

        }


        break;

        case 'D': {

            d = false;

        }

        break;
        
        }

        if (wParam == 'F') {

            SetWindowText(hWnd, L"third title");
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"jgjfgdfg", L"uuuvloa", MB_OK);

        }

    }

    break;

    case WM_CHAR:
    {
        if (wParam != 'w') {

            std::wstring title = L"aaaaa";    
            title.push_back((wchar_t)wParam);
            SetWindowTextW(hWnd, title.c_str());

        }

    }

    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {

        unsigned short xPos = LOWORD(lParam);
        unsigned short yPos = HIWORD(lParam);

        if (!lbutton) {

            prevx = LOWORD(lParam);
            prevy = HIWORD(lParam);

            lbutton = true;

        }

        if (lbutton) {

            xPos = LOWORD(lParam);
            yPos = HIWORD(lParam);

            HPEN penna = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(0, 0, 150));

            SelectObject(device_context, penna);

            MoveToEx(device_context, prevx, prevy, nullptr);
            LineTo(device_context, xPos, yPos);

            ReleaseDC(hWnd, device_context);

            lbutton = false;

        }

        SetWindowText(hWnd, L"second title");    

        std::wstring titolo = L" X: " + std::to_wstring(xPos) + L" Y: " + std::to_wstring(yPos);
        SetWindowText(hWnd, titolo.c_str());
    }

    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        SetWindowText(hWnd, L"uwu");
    }

    break;

    case WM_CLOSE:  //case window get closed
    {
        PostQuitMessage(69); //  "the task ended with code 0"
    }

    break;

    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

}

//
//entry point

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,   
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,   
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,   
    _In_ int nCmdShow   
) {

    std::cout << "aaaa" << std::endl;

    const auto pClassName = L"title";

    
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 }; 
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc); 
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;    
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;    
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;  
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;  
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;   
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;   
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;   
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;    
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;    
    wc.lpszClassName = pClassName;    
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;   

    RegisterClassEx(&wc); 

    

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx( 

        0, pClassName, 
        L"window name", 
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        100, 100, 720, 480,  
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr 
    );

    
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    MSG msg; 
    BOOL gResult;

    while ((gResult = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) > 0) {

        
        TranslateMessage(&msg);  
        DispatchMessage(&msg);  

    }

    if (gResult == -1) {

        return -1;

    }
    else {

        return msg.wParam;  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need help in two parts of the code:

1. movement of the pixels with wasd
2. the LineTo() of WM_LBUTTONDOWN

Issues:

1 (wasd): **SOLVED**

if I'm holding pressed w and then i press for example a, but without stopping pressing w, it stops recognising w, and executes the code just like I'm pressing a only.

2 (dots):    **SOLVED**

in WM_LBUTTONDOWN I have two if statements. lbutton should be false the first time then every time I click the boolean should change value (if it's false become true and if it's true become false) so when it's the first time i click i store coordinates on "prevx" and "prevy", then when i click a second time i save "posx" and "posy" then i draw a line starting from "prevx""prevy" ending to "posx""posy"

what happens instead:

(I printed with std::cout values there)

the boolean is always true, or always false. prevx is always the same as posx, prevy is always the same of posy.

i tried:

to move "bool lbutton = false;" outside the function as a global variable, or outside the switch.
the same of lbutton with prevx and prevy;

EDIT: solved everything, thank you all for help

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting all of the key flags to false whenever a message is received? Seems like you want to use `WM_KEYUP` instead to reset a flag based on your description of how you want it to work. `GetAsyncKeyState` may be a better choice for determining what keys are down at any particular time since keydown and keyup messages aren't guaranteed to be paired.

Comment: Consider also that GDI resources are limited in number, When you create a new object, i.e. a pen, you have to dispose it after use with `DeleteObject()`, or after a number of iteration the program will freeze. A better solution, if the object doesn't change between invocations, is to create it just one time, i.e. during `WM_CREATE` message execution, and save it in a static variable. This will also speed-up the program.

Comment: 1, (wasd):
The reason is that there is no way to recognize that two buttons are pressed at the same time. When you holding pressed `w` and then press `a`, the application only recognize `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your WM_PAINT is missing a break statement. The will fall through to the WM_KEYDOWN. I'm not sure if that's your only bug or is your issue. But it's got to be addressed.

```
    switch (msg) {  
    case WM_PAINT:
    {

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        int size = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                SetPixel(hdc, dotx + i, doty + j, color);
            }
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    }  // AFTER EndPaint... the code continues onto the next case statement

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
```

Also your entire WM_KEYDOWN statement can be simplified to this:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:    
{
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case 'W':
        w = true;
        break;
    case 'A':
        a = true;
        break;
    case 'S':
        s = true;
        break;
    case 'D':

        d = true;
    }
    doty += w ? -1  : 0;
    dotx += a ? -1 : 0;
    dotx += d ? 1 : 0;
    doty += s ? 1 : 0;
    if (w || a || d || s) {
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
    break;
}
```

Similar cleanup can be applied to the WM_KEYUP code.

But there's another bug or issue. Your WM_KEYDOWN is handling a lot of two button down cases.  But at most, only one of the four variables, `a`, `s`, `w`, and `d`, are getting toggled from false to true.  So all of those statements such as `if (w == true && a == true)` will always evaluate to false. **Maybe you wanted those four bool variables to be static**?